# asp.net decompiled function is same but ndepend shows difference

Tags: ndepend

I have decompiled 2 .net 2.0 dlls (using a decompiler tool) and when I compare a function both are same. But when I compare these 2 assemblies, ndepend shows difference in ILInstructions and NBLinesOfCode.

Please let me know why ndepend is showing the function difference but decompiled code is same? if having differences (IL Instructions and LOC) in ndepend means the functionality is really different for 2 dlls?

What steps I can take to make the 2 assemblies same so that ndepend doesn't show difference in that function?

Please note I have lost original source code and I am trying to re-build the source code to make it original dll.

Comment: Did you compile the 2 versions with the same version of the compiler? Does the IL code instructions set decompiled is exactly the same?

Comment: I am sure both the version of compiler were same. The IL code instruction are decompiling exactly the same to C# but when I view the IL code using ILDASM there are lot of differences in those so ndepend should show these are different. After I worked on few functions it seems the overall functionality are same but IL Instructions are different in those 2 assemblies. I am really not finding an easy way to make both IL instructions same in both the dll for those functions so that ndepend will show them as same? Different decompilers decompile to different code same functionality (but IL changes)

Comment: For example, one decompiler decompiled both the original and new dll function and used "!=" in if...else. But when IL is compared it was showing difference, so after understanding the IL I realized that the original IL is using "==" (ofcourse with respective correct if...else logic functionally). So I changed the if...else to use "==" instead "!=" which was given by decompiler (for both the assemblies). After that I compared the IL instructions were same and ndepend also showed same. But this was not easy luckily this was a small function but I am struggling with big functions to make IL same

Comment: If version of the compiler is same, how to explain that the exact same C# method is compiled to a different set of IL instructions?

Comment: No. I am saying different IL instructions are decompiling to same C# method by decompilers. I don't know what was the original C# method (inside original dll) and this is something I am struggling to find/code when I am creating my own new dll.

Comment: and yes your point is valid...I should try to reconfirm if this is because of compiler version.

Comment: I understand now that issue is more related to decompiling the dll and IL code. So asked another question. Not related to ndepend.